# The route addition failed: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-7, windows, routing

I am trying to add a route line in command prompt  :

```
D:\Users\OM-11>route add -p 10.9.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.6.2 metric 21 if 192.168.6.26
```

CP is opened in administrator mode, my Windows 7 is located in drive d:

and I received this error line :

> The route addition failed: The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 4):

#### The route addition failed: The system cannot find the file specified.

```
route add -p 10.9.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.6.2 metric 21 if 192.168.6.26
```

You are using an IP address `192.168.6.26` instead of the **interface number**

---

#### Syntax

> Add a route:
>
> ```
> ROUTE [-f] [-p] ADD [destination_host] [MASK subnet_mask_value] [gateway] 
>                                        [METRIC metric] [IF interface_no.]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Key
>
> ...
>
> `interface_no` The interface number (1,2,...) for the specified route.

Source [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) - Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.

Comment: @Ahmet I'd like to point out that much of that is optional.  I suggest leaving off "-p" until you confirm the route is working.  You can also leave off everything after the destination (starting with the word "metric"); those are optional and generally not needed for more basic usage.

Comment: @TOOGAM Ahmet hasn't been seen since "Sep 14 '14". I was just updaating an old answer ;)